# Sessions on PHP and Apache don't work anyway

Tags: php, apache, session

I'm facing a big trouble. Sessions variables don't work on PHP and Apache 2. I already tried a lot of things. But I have no more ideas. Please, help!

**test1.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', 'www.domain.com');

echo "test1.php";

$_SESSION['VAR1'] = 'My Value';

header('location:test2.php');
session_write_close();
exit();
?>
```

**test2.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', 'www.domain.com');

echo "test2.php <br />";
echo 'VAR 1 = '.$_SESSION['VAR1'];
?>
```

**The return**

```
test2.php
VAR 1 =
```

**The Environment**

```
PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.19
Server API  Apache 2.0 Handler
session.auto_start  On
session.cookie_domain   no value
session.cookie_httponly On
session.cookie_lifetime 0
session.save_path   /var/lib/php5/
session.serialize_handler   php
session.use_cookies On
session.use_only_cookies    On
```

**Things that I have tried**

- sudo chmod -R 777 /var/lib/php5/ and sudo chown -R www-data /var/lib/php5/

Thank you!

Comment: does it work if you comment out your `ini_set()` lines from both test1 and test2?

Comment: I just ran the code on my server and it worked fine (I took out the ini_set lines), so it is something in your settings. I looked at my ini file and most settings are the same except session.save_path is commented out, not sure you need that, or at least try to comment it out and see if that is your problem.

Comment: Thanks BizzyBob and Katie. I tried to comment ini_set() and tried comment session.save_path too, but nothing changed.